# Pkzip 2.5 skipping dirs whose name begins with dot

Tags: pkzip

I normally (on Windows) package up a directory into a single file with Pkzip 2.5,

```
pkzip25 -add -dir ...
```

which recursively includes subdirectories and their contents. A problem I've encountered is when subdirectories begin with a dot, e.g. .settings directory created by Eclipse; Pkzip doesn't go into those directories. I can't find anything about this in the help text or on Google; is there a way to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [pkzip 2.5 manual](http://ricardo.ecn.wfu.edu/~cottrell/pkzip.html), pkzip considers as hidden all names that start with a dot.

Try to add the parameter "-filetype=all", in order to process files with all file types (includes hidden).

Comment: It seems that parameter is only available on UNIX.

Comment: Ah, so you're on Windows. It would be a nice catch-22 if the dot-behavior was carried over from Linux, but not its antidote! In that case, there are many other zip products (like 7-Zip) which are much newer and more efficient.

Comment: Quite so! Yeah, I've now tested 7zip on the same scenario and it works correctly, so I'll probably start using it for this purpose.